# TinCan Js Completion and Time Spent

Tags: scorm

I am new to TinCan, I am building a course where I need to set the completion status to completed and also the time needs to be recorded. I am using an LMS and also scormcloud for testing.

Currently, the completed status is working but it's not capturing the time spent.

This is the code:

```
var tincan = new TinCan({url: location.href});
tincan.sendStatement(new TinCan.Statement({
    verb: 'completed',
    result: {
        success: true
    }       
}));
```

Answer (score 3):

To include duration in that statement you should use the result.duration property. This is an ISO 8601 duration representing the attempt duration (rather than session duration). I actually have a [blog on duration](http://tincanapi.com/blog/?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=blog?pmc=em-1) due out in the next month or so that I hope you'll find helpful.

I'd also recommend using a full verb object and using result.completion instead of result.success for a completion statement.

So your final code will be:

```
var tincan = new TinCan({url: location.href});
tincan.sendStatement(new TinCan.Statement({
    verb: {
        id: "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/completed",
        display:{
            "en-US": "completed"
        }
    },
    result: {
        completion: true,
        duration: "PT21.896S"
    }       
}));
```

Note also that it be may best not to rely on the activity definition from the query string, but I appreciate you may be keeping the code sample short for the sake of the question.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for the updated code. I tested the new code, and now I can't get anything to post. I am using tincan js, also a tincan xml in the root like this: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<tincan xmlns="http://projecttincan.com/tincan.xsd">
 <activities>
  <activity id="http://www.myurl.com/courses/testingscore" type="http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/course">
   <name>testingscore</name>
   <description lang="en-US">testingscore</description>
   <launch lang="en-us">index.html</launch>
  </activity>
 </activities>
</tincan>

Comment: From looking at the console, I keep getting this error message: Object with name 'statement' could not be created from the provided JSON. Error message: The time interval specified ('PT21.896S') is not in a supported format.

Comment: That duration is in the right format and in fact was copied and pasted from a statement I generated with TinCanJS and sent to SCORM Cloud 2 days ago. Are you still testing against SCORM Cloud? Are you using the [latest version of TinCanJS](http://tincanapi.com/libraries/?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=page&utm_campaign=libraries?pmc=em-1)? Can I see your new code?

Comment: Andrew - have you updated your blog yet? I can't find your post on duration, but I would find it helpful. I'm still unclear how to scope it. For example, when users take four 1-hour sessions to complete a course, would they not save 3 "attempts" and one "complete" - each with a 1 hour duration? Or are the durations cumulative, such that each duration gets added to the previous? I've noticed the SCORMEngine’s 2004 to Tin Can conversion seems to take the latter approach, but I can't find any documentation in the spec that it should be done that way. Thoughts?

Comment: Hi Tim, We didn't want to post the blog post until our prototypes have been updated and unfortunately there's been a long delay getting the new prototypes through the peer review process so the blog is on hold. In the scenario you describe, I'd expect session duration to be recorded at 1 hour per session and attempt duration to be recorded as 4 hours. If you post a new question I can answer more fully than in these comments.